# Find $f(x)$ if $f'(x)=f(x) + \int_0^1 f(x)dx$ and $f(0)=1$

Tags: calculus, ordinary-differential-equations, integro-differential-equations

Find $f(x)$ if $$f'(x)=f(x) + \int_0^1 f(x)dx,\quad f(0)=1$$

**My attempt**:

Let $\int_0^1 f(x)dx=C_1$ and $f(x)=y$ so $f'(x)= \frac{dy}{dx}$. We have to solve $\frac{dy}{dx}= y+C_1$ or $$x+C_2= \ln|y+C_1|$$

which implies $$e^{x+C_2}= y+C_1$$

Substituting the given initial  value we get $ e^{C_2}=1+C_2$.

However my book says the function is
$\frac{2e^x}{3-e} + \frac{1-e}{3-e} $ and I'm not sure how this answer is right.

Comment: Just wondering, should the upper bound in the integral be x instead for the question to be solvable, was it perhaps a printing mistake ?

Comment: I don't know why but my answer is coming $f(x)=\frac{2e^x}{3-e}-\frac{e-1}{3-e}$ ....it might be wrong as I did it in a hurry...can someone confirm$?$

Comment: @MathStackexchangeIsNotSoBad, yeah my bad, that is the answer, typo, sorry

Comment: You can also integrate $f(x)$ from $0$ to $1$ to get a second equation for the constants. Solve this system of equations for the constants, and you’ll end up with the correct answer.

Comment: The main thing here is to first assume the integral as a constant, say $A$. Then solve the differential equation and find $f(x)$ in terms of $A$ using the given condition $f(0)=1$. Then you have $f(x)$ with you (in terms of A). Then just do $\int_0^1 f(x) dx =A$ from here find A substitute back in $f(x)$

Comment: Or you can also differentiate the given expression and then continue

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Differentiating both sides of the equation we know that: $$f'(x)=f(x)+\int_0^1f(x)dx\:\Longrightarrow\:f''(x)=f'(x)$$
The latter is a second order linear ODE with constant coefficients. It's general solution is: $$f(x)=Ae^x+B$$
The fact that $f(0)=1$ tells us that $A+B=1$, so we can rewrite $f(x)$ as: $$f(x)=Ae^x+(1-A)$$ The integral from $0$ to $1$ of this function is:
$$\int_0^1 f(x)dx=\left[Ae^x+(1-A)x\right]_{x=0}^{x=1}=Ae+(1-A)-A=A(e-2)+1$$
Substituting in the original equation we get:
$$\begin{align*}Ae^x=Ae^x+(1-A)+A(e-2)+1\:&\Longrightarrow\:0=2+A(e-3)\\&\Longrightarrow\:A=\frac{2}{3-e}\end{align*}$$
So: $$f(x)=\frac{2}{3-e}e^x+\frac{1-e}{3-e}$$
**Edit:**
Your reasoning was also correct. At the point where you get $x+C_2=\ln|y+C_1|$, substituting the initial value gives you $C_2=\ln|1+C_1|\:\Longrightarrow\:e^{C_2}=|1+C_1|$ (and not $e^{C_2}=1+C_2$ as you wrote, but I'm sure that was just a typo). So:
$$f(x)=e^{x+C_2}-C_1=|1+C_1|e^x-C_1$$ At this point, using the definition of $C_1$, we can conclude that:
$$C_1:=\int_0^1f(x)dx=\int_0^1\left(|1+C_1|e^x-C_1\right)dx=|1+C_1|(e-1)-C_1$$
It is not difficult to see that the solution of the equation written above is precisely $$C_1=-\frac{1-e}{3-e}$$
Thus:
$$f(x)=|1+C_1|e^x-C_1=\frac{2}{3-e}e^x+\frac{1-e}{3-e}$$

Comment: oh, thanks so much!

Comment: @mathandphysicsforever You're welcome. I've edited my answer in order to add further details and to show you that your way of reasoning was also correct. If you think my answer was helpful to you please consider accepting it. Thank you so much, and have a nice day.